# How to resolve class version conflict?

Tags: java, jar

Suppose we have an application that rely on lib1.jar and lib2.jar.

In lib1.jar, it contains for example some slf4j-v1 classes.

In lib2.jar, it contains same but different version slf4j-v2 classes.

Now I am building my own jar. What is the best way to resolve the version conflict problem?

Comment: No, I am not using maven. We build our application using ant

Comment: can the lib1.jar and lib2.jar be modified ? And are those slf4j class packed in those libx.jars ?

Comment: @GavinXiong I am not sure, but I don't think lib1.jar, lib2.jar can be modified, since they are open source libraries. And yes those classes are packed into the jars.

Comment: @performanceuser What are those lib1 and lib2 actually ? May be you should separate them with slf4j classes on source-code level, still I don't understand why those libs contain slf4j class.

Comment: They are different open source libraries that I need to use in my application. Those lib may use different version of slf4j.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone is interested in the answer, I ended up using "jarjar" to rename the package in one jar.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do it would be to merge lib1.jar + slf4j-v1.jar => lib1.jar and lib2.jar + slf4j-v2.jar => lib2.jar, in this case it should work as you want it.

Comment: No, slf4j-v1.class are packed into lib1.jar, and same for lib2.jar. Then when both lib1&2.jar are loaded, there is a problem